# copy/paste with mouse doesn't work anymore

Tags: mouse

For some times now, i've lost the copy/paste function with the mouse (2e button click), I can't only copy paste with keyboard now?

Does anybody knows how to re-enable it??

Answer (score 0):

Try to install [gpointing-device-settings](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gpointing-device-settings/)

```
sudo apt-get install gpointing-device-settings
```

You then check the  'use wheel emulation'.

[image]

Comment: i guess i'm unlucky as running gpointing-device-settings gives me a segmentation fault on ubuntu 13.10......